# How to position the home content after the side nav bar?

Tags: html, css

Here I'm providing my HTML and CSS codes. I have already missed something in the home content of css. Can anyone tell me how to position the sections after the side navigation bar?

```css
.home-content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100%-240px);
  left: 240px;
}

.t {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  ;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
</div>
<div class="home-content">
  <div class="t">
    <h2>Home Content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ` Can anyone tell me how to position the sections after the side navigation bar?` what exactly do you want?

Comment: i want to display the h2 tag which in the home-content div next to the side nav bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, use`display: flex` with a wrapper div as per the example below. More information on flexbox at [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and a nice intro from Kevin Powell on [youtube](https://youtu.be/u044iM9xsWU)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 15ch;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.home-content {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.t {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  ;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="sidebar">
    This is the sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="home-content">
    <div class="t">
      <h2>Home Content</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex for this. Consider wrapping your whole body code into a div and add poperties:

```css
#wapper_div{
  width:100%;
  display : flex;
  justify-content : flex-start;
}
#sidebar {
  flex : 2; /* as per your choice */
}
#home{
  flex: 9; /* as per your choice */
 }
```